# Getting a simple syntax error when using a gate primitive?

Tags: verilog

So I'm trying to implement a basic ALU for my first Verilog course, DSD II. Xilinx keeps reporting an error on the lines where I call the gate primitives "and"/"or", but I've used them in previous assignments this way with no errors. Can anybody see what I'm missing?

Code:

```
module ALU(a,b, opcode, carry, Y, zeroflag);

  input [15:0]a;
  input [15:0]b;
  input [3:0]opcode;
  wire In = {opcode,a,b};
  output reg carry;
  output reg [15:0]Y;
  output reg zeroflag;

  always @(In)
  begin
    case(opcode)

    //Zero Op
    4'b0000 : 
      begin
        Y = 16'h00;
        carry = 0;
        zeroflag = 1;
      end

    //Add
    4'b0001:
      begin
        Ripple_Carry_Adder RCA1(Y,carry,a,b,carry);
      end

    //Subtract
    4'b0010:
      begin
      end

    //Multiply
    4'b0011:
      begin
        Y = a*b;

        if (Y > 65535)
          carry = 1;
        else
          carry = 0;

        if (Y == 0)
          zeroflag = 1;
        else 
          zeroflag = 0;
      end

    //Divide
    4'b0100:
      begin
        Y = a/b;

        if (Y > 65535)
          carry = 1;
        else
          carry = 0;

        if (Y == 0)
          zeroflag = 1;
        else 
        zeroflag = 0;
      end

    //And
    4'b0110:
      begin
        and(Y, a, b);

        if (Y == 0)
          zeroflag = 1;
        else
          zeroflag = 0;
      end

    //Or
    4'b0111:
      begin
        or(Y,a,b);

        if (Y == 0)
          zeroflag = 1;
        else
          zeroflag = 0;
      end

    //Zero Test
    4'b1001:
      if((a || b) == 0)
        begin
          Y = 0;
          zeroflag = 1;
          carry = 0;
        end

    //Greater Than
    4'b1010:
      begin
        if(a > b)
          Y = a;
        else if (b > a)
          Y = b;
        else
          Y = 16'h00;

        if (Y == 0)
          zeroflag = 1;
        else
          zeroflag = 0;
      end

    //Equal
    4'b1011:
      begin
        if (a == b)
          Y = 16'h11;
        else
          Y = 16'h00;

        if (Y == 0)
          zeroflag = 1;
        else
          zeroflag = 0;
      end

    //Less Than
    4'b1100:
      begin
        if(a < b)
          Y = a;
        else if (b < a)
          Y = b;
        else
          Y = 16'h00;

        if (Y == 0)
          zeroflag = 1;
        else
          zeroflag = 0;
      end

    default :
      begin 
        Y = 16'hxx;
        carry = 1'bx;
        zeroflag = 1'bx;
      end
    endcase

  end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

You are instantiating the primitives (as well as the module `Ripple_Carry_Adder`) inside of an always block, which is not allowed.

Any time you create a module or primitive instance, think of it as placing down a physical piece of hardware.  You cannot create it conditionally - it is always there.

So for something like an ALU design, you may want all the operations (add, sub, multiply, divide, etc.) to *always* happen, and then select the desired output depending on the opcode.

Comment: Ok so I guess I should put those calls above the always block and connect the outputs to Y by using wires, thanks!

Comment: @schmittens: yes! and then use a mux (either behaviorally or instantiate it) to send their outputs to the ALU output based on the value of the opcode!

Comment: @schmittens they are not calls, they are instantiations. They represent real physical things, not just functions to be simulated.